# Key Repeat no longer works on Windows 7 Lenovo Windows 700 laptop

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

The title pretty much sums up my problem.  I can type fine, but holding down the key doesn't repeat, including the arrow keys which is super-annoying.

"Filter Keys" in the Ease of access center is not turned on, so that's not the problem.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Also, the numeric keypad on the right is not working at all -- not just that it won't repeat, but there is no response at all to the numbers, the enter key, the numlk key.  The purple Fn+NumLk which usually opens the calc program doesn't work.  It's like it's totally disconnected.

Comment: WRT your update - do any of the other Fn keys work?  I almost wonder if the keyboard connector is dislodged...

Answer (score 1):

Switching off the "Filter keys" in Windows Accessibility Centre will solve it.

(How it got switched on in my case I have no idea as I'm the only one using this laptop.)

Answer (score 0):

Control panel -> Keyboard

Adjust the repeat speed there.
http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/8712-keyboard-repeat-delay-repeat-rate.html

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't it because you can't disable repetition ENTIRELY there.  The registry flags further in that thread might be worth checking just in case...

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work, and the registry settings looked OK.  My suspicion is that there's some Lenovo-specific setting I've accidentally activated, but I can't find anything about that.

Comment: @Clyde - I supported these laptops for years, and currently am working for a reseller of them, and this is the first I've heard of this. :/  I'm thinking it's either some obscure Windows thing or else another piece of software you have installed, but unfortunately I have no clue!

Comment: Then I have no idea.  The only thing I've heard of in Windows is the accessibility settings in the ease of access center.  I know that's turned off...